# Apache hive query syntax

Tags: hadoop

**Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 32:1 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'count' in expression specification**

```
select  bid,pid,cdate,chour ,'n' in_out,count(hc) as total 
from
(
select a.mac,a.cdate,a.chour,
(select count(1) from bengo.n_hour_count_1 b 
where a.mac=b.mac and a.cdate=b.cdate and a.chour=b.chour+1) as hc
from  bengo.n_hour_count_1 a
having hc=0
) g
GROUP BY cdate,chour;
```

Comment: You are trying to use subquery as a column name which is invalid.

Comment: format  for better [read](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)